# Partial search with regex?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

If I am using a `RegEx` as a mask for a `TextBox` and the mask should allow a format of `000-XXXXXX`, meaning for example that it allows 3 letters, a dash, then 6 numbers, how can I allow the user to only have to type in the first 3 characters of the mask to use in searching and not have what they typed in be invalid because it does not satisfy a the complete `RegEx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make parts of the regex optional:

```
^\d{3}(?:-\d{0,6})?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
\d{3}    # Match 3 digits
(?:      # Try to match... 
 -       #  a dash
 \d{0,6} #  followed by up to 6 digits
)?       # but make that part of the match optional
$        # End of string
```

Comment: What does `?:` and the last `?` mean?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group (needed so the following `?` (which means "zero or one") applies to the entire sub-regex enclosed within).

Comment: Great thanks for the good explanation.  If the TextBox already has a dash in it because this is a mask specified on an input textbox, would it not work.

Comment: As long as there are three digits before the dash, yes, it will work.

Comment: What if they enter `333-H`, would it now fail because it is incomplete or would it still try to do a partial match.  Basically, they can enter as many characters as they want, but the first 3 are absolutely required, but if they entered more, it should still do a wild-card search.

Comment: Also, how do I allow 6 letters after the dash and not 6 numbers? Would it be `^\d{3}(?:-[A-Za-z]{0,6})?$`

Comment: For international uppercase letters, use `\p{Lu}` instead of `\d` (any case: `\p{L}`); for ASCII-only letters, use `[A-Z]` or `[A-Za-z]`, depending on whether lowercase is allowed or not.